# How to append numbers to empty dataframe column from conditional for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dummy-variable

I created a new column for each state (there are only 3 different states) with empty values in each row. Im using a for loop to loop through the original "State" column and if the conditional is met for the state I want, a value of 1 is placed in the corresponding row of the column "New York" for example

```
for i in states:
        if i == "New York":
            dataset["New York"].replace("", 1)
```

Im expecting to see 1s in the new york column at the corresponding location in the "State" column where the value is "New York" but all it returns is 0s

Comment: what's `states` the original column in the dataframe?

Comment: I think you want [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, probably this is not the optimal solution in computational cost, but u can only use `iterrows` function:

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["OrginalState","State1","State2", "State3"])

df1.loc[0] = ["State1",None,None,None]
df1.loc[1] = ["State2",None,None,None]
df1.loc[2] = ["State3",None,None,None]

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if(row["OrginalState"] == "State1"):
        df1.loc[index]["State1"] = 1
    if(row["OrginalState"] == "State2"):
        df1.loc[index]["State2"] = 1
    if(row["OrginalState"] == "State3"):
        df1.loc[index]["State3"] = 1

print df1
```

Output:

```
  OrginalState State1 State2 State3
0       State1      1   None   None
1       State2   None      1   None
2       State3   None   None      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to use one-hot encoding. There are multiple ways to do this:

1. **Use pd.get_dummies**:

   ```
   one_hot_df = pd.get_dummies(orig_df['States'])
   ```

   To combine this with the original dataframe:

   ```
   orig_df.join(one_hot_df)
   ```
2. **Use OneHotEncoder from sklearn**:

   If you might have new data to encode in the future (for instance, when you want to encode testing dataset) [sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) also comes in handy.